# Link Mac h-o Id Error With Xcode 4.2 With ios 5

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

When I M Trying To open Application With Xcode 4.2 With Ios 5 I Got Following Error ....Present Application Working In xcode 3.2.5 Up To ios 4.2 Fine . I want to Upgrade To Ios 5.Please Help Me Out.

How can I Solve The Following Issue

Ld /Users/HB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThinQFitness-gvejpzlfynofgpeaannlsyrlfnym/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ThinQFitness.app/ThinQFitness normal i386
    cd "/Users/HB/Desktop/MyDaily Works/2NOV/ThinQFitness-10th oct 2011"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/HB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThinQFitness-gvejpzlfynofgpeaannlsyrlfnym/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/HB/Desktop/MyDaily Works/2NOV/ThinQFitness-10th oct 2011/Classes" -F/Users/HB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThinQFitness-gvejpzlfynofgpeaannlsyrlfnym/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Library/System/Frameworks -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Library/System/Frameworks -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Library/System/Frameworks -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Library/System/Frameworks -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Library/System/Frameworks -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Library/System/Frameworks -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Library/System/Frameworks "-F/Users/HB/Desktop/MyDaily Works/2NOV/ThinQFitness-10th oct 2011" -filelist /Users/HB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThinQFitness-gvejpzlfynofgpeaannlsyrlfnym/Build/Intermediates/ThinQFitness.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ThinQFitness.build/Objects-normal/i386/ThinQFitness.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30103 /Users/HB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThinQFitness-gvejpzlfynofgpeaannlsyrlfnym/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libObjectiveFlickr.a /Users/HB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThinQFitness-gvejpzlfynofgpeaannlsyrlfnym/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectiveFlickr/ObjectiveFlickr -framework Foundation -weak_framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lxml2.2.7.3 -lz.1.2.3 -framework CFNetwork -framework QuartzCore -framework StoreKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreText -lsqlite3.0 -o /Users/HB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThinQFitness-gvejpzlfynofgpeaannlsyrlfnym/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ThinQFitness.app/ThinQFitness

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: while running on Simulator or device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I sloved the above problem its problem with Frame Work reference
>   Missing